# Custom compile-time checks

Tags: c#, vector, algebra

I don´t think that this question has (or can) been answered, or at least I didn´t find the answer: is it possible to create custom compile-time checks?

The specific situation is that I am programming a quantum spaces calculator, and while you could have vectors (1,0,0) and (1,0), I should modify certain operations between them as they belong to certain spaces. Even more, you could have (1,0) and (1,0) but neither of them belonging to the same spaces, so the operations between them would be different. But I don´t find a clever (not run-time) way to do this because they all belong to the same class so they have the same operators!

Also, the size of the vectors is arbitrary (from 0 to infinite) so I can´t make a class for all of them as a "Tuple".

Comment: there are of course better ways to represent a vector than a tuple, like all kinds of IEnumerable implementations. Think you have more of a modelling problem here than a problem with compile time checks. I do not know that much about your domain, but perhaps you can describe the problem you want to solve a bit more precise.

Comment: I´ll try: you have arbitrary sized vectors, and you can perform operations between them. For example you can combine two vectors. The new vector size will be size1*size2. But this operation makes no sense if the vectors you are combining belong to the same space. By space I mean the "data" it represents. For example you could have a 3-vector representing color and a 3-vector representing position, you could combine them to create the position-color vector. But I dont want to remember the space of every vector, I would like the compiler to do that for me.

Comment: From your description you might want to look at F# and units of measure: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233243.aspx

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I wasn´t aware, thank you. @Lee I was hoping to make it with C#, because I might use it with Unity. I love functional languages but I find it hard using them between different programs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use generics to prevent operations between different "vector" classes something like following concept code:

```
class Vector<Traits> : IEnumerable<double> 
{
    public static Vector<Traits> 
        operator + (Vector<Traits> left, Vector<Traits> right) { ... } 
}

var v1 = new Vector<MyTraitsOne>(2);    
var v2 = new Vector<MyTraitsOther>(2);

var r = v1 + v2; // should fail.
```

(`Traits` class as generic's parameter in sample is solely to distinguish different vectors of `double`, but in real case there may even be good usage of such class)

Comment: This comes very very close to what I want, but this brings up the problem of creating a new class for every "Trait" I would like to have.

Comment: In the end this is the best answer, and it´s even good that the user is forced to create a new class for every space, I like it a lot. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Code Contracts](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/) to describe the non-trivial assumptions about class state and operations that are allowed on it. Some of the contracts can be checked at compile time, and others will generate a runtime exception.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want to look at unit tests. Not compile time, but pre-run-time checks on your cod. In your unit tests you'd specify the constraints your code should handle. And if a developer breaks these constraints, unit tests will fail, highlighting the problem.

People write books on unit-tests, so can't really write a lot about them, but you can start here: http://anthonyjbrown.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/true-beginners-guide-to-unit-testing-in.html

Answer (score 0):

As I already mentioned in my comment, I think you have more a modelling problem here than real problems with compile time checks.

But, as you ask, those checks might be achieved by leveraging something like postsharp.

[Codeproject article on aspect oriented programming using Postsharp as a starter](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/337564/Aspect-Oriented-Programming-Using-Csharp-and-PostS)