# Vector math dimension consistency check at compile-time

Tags: c#

I am creating a linear algebra library in C#, and I would like to force dimension inconsistency errors up to compile-time. I've implemented a similar solution to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20777265/custom-compile-time-checks), where the trait I use is a class that uniquely maps to an integer. The problem is for every possible size I would like my Vectors to have, I would need to create a class with a unique name to represent it.

Here is an example of that implementation:

```
public class Vector<T> where T: ISize, new()
{
    static readonly T size = new T();
    List<double> values;

    public Vector(List<double> values)
    {
        if (values.Count != size.Size)
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();

        this.values = new List<double>(values);
    }

    public double Get(int index)
    {
        return values[index];
    }

    public Vector<T> Add(Vector<T> other)
    {
        var vv = new List<double>();

        for (int ii = 0; ii < size.Size; ++ii)
            vv.Add(other.Get(ii) + this.values[ii]);

        return new Vector<T>(vv);
    }
}

public interface ISize
{
    int Size { get; }
}

public class S1 : ISize
{
    public int Size
    {
        get { return 1; }
    }
}

public class S2 : ISize
{
    public int Size
    {
        get { return 2; }
    }
}
```

And here's an example of its usage:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var v1 = new Vector<S2>(new List<double>() { 1, 2 });
        var v2 = new Vector<S2>(new List<double>() { 10, -4 });
        var z1 = new Vector<S1>(new List<double>() { 10 });

        // works
        var v3 = v1.Add(v2);

        // complie-time error
        var z2 = z1.Add(v1);
    }
}
```

This works quite well for my purposes, except for the fact that I would need to create a different implementation of ISize for every possible Vector size. Is there any way for me to implement the Vector class that would allow me to get around this problem?

Comment: Without the C++ equivalent of "non-type template parameters", I don't think it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get a compile-time error, you need to have different types. C# does not have a concept that let's you define a type parameter that itself takes a kind of value parameters - which is what you would need to do this.

Therefore, I don't think what you are asking is possible.

I think there might be a way to make unique types for family of vector instances using anonymous types, but that's going to be quirky and I don't think it would provide the type safety that you want.

C++ has such a concept in templates (so it's not unreasonable), just not possible in C#.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a single N-dimentional `Vector` class with compile time type checking, but it's pretty messy.  What we're creating here is LISP style linked-lists, but through generic type arguments rather than purely out of object references via fields.

```
public interface IVector
{
    double Value { get; }
    IVector Tail { get; }
}
public class Vector<T> : IVector
    where T : IVector
{
    internal Vector(double value, T tail)
    {
        Value = value;
        Tail = tail;
    }

    public double Value { get; private set; }
    public T Tail { get; private set; }

    public Vector<Vector<T>> Add(double value)
    {
        return new Vector<Vector<T>>(value, this);
    }
}
internal class EmptyVector : IVector
{
    public double Value
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public IVector Tail
    {
        get { return null; }
    }
}

public static class Vector
{
    public static readonly Vector<IVector> Empty = new Vector<IVector>(
        0, new EmptyVector());
    public static IEnumerable<double> AllValues(this IVector vector)
    {
        IVector current = vector;
        while (current != Vector.Empty && current != null)
        {
            yield return current.Value;
            current = current.Tail;
        };
    }
}
```

This allows us to write:

```
var v1 = Vector.Empty.Add(1).Add(2);
var v2 = Vector.Empty.Add(10).Add(-4);
var z1 = Vector.Empty.Add(10);


v1 = v2;//works, as they are the same type
z1 = v2;//fails, as they aren't the same type, since they're a different size
```

This allows allows you to write a method that accepts a vector of a particular size.  It's not convenient, and it doesn't scale, but it works.  If you want, say, a 3D vector as a parameter, you can write:

```
public static void Foo(Vector<Vector<Vector<IVector>>> vector)
{
    var first = vector.Value;
    var second = vector.Tail.Value;
    var third = vector.Tail.Tail.Value;
}
```